# Crop satellite image image based on a historical image with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have the following problem, I have a pair of two images one historical and one present-day satellite image and as the historical image covers a smaller area I want to crop the satellite images. Here one can see the code I wrote for this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import imutils
import math

entries = os.listdir('../')

refImage = 0
histImages = []
def loadImage(index):
    referenceImage = cv2.imread("../" + 'ref_' + str(index) + '.png')

    top = int(0.5 * referenceImage.shape[0])  # shape[0] = rows
    bottom = top
    left = int(0.5 * referenceImage.shape[1])  # shape[1] = cols
    right = left

    referenceImage = cv2.copyMakeBorder(referenceImage, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, (0,0,0))
    counter = 0
    for entry in entries:
        if entry.startswith("image_"+str(index)):
            refImage = referenceImage.copy()
            histImage = cv2.imread("../" + entry)
            #histImages.append(img)
            points = np.loadtxt("H2OPM/"+"CP_"+ entry[6:9] + ".txt", delimiter=",")

            vector_image1 = [points[0][0] - points[1][0], points[0][1] - points[1][1]] #hist
            vector_image2 = [points[0][2] - points[1][2], points[0][3] - points[1][3]] #ref

            angle = angle_between(vector_image1, vector_image2)

            hhist, whist, chist = histImage.shape

            rotatedImage = imutils.rotate(refImage, angle)

            x = int(points[0][2] - points[0][0])
            y = int(points[1][2] - points[1][0])

            crop_img = rotatedImage[x+left:x+left+hhist, y+top:y+top+whist]

            print("NewImageWidth:", (y+top+whist)-(y+top),(x+left+hhist)-(x+left))

            print(entry)
            print(x,y)


            counter += 1
            #histImage = cv2.line(histImage, (points[0][0], ), end_point, color, thickness) 
            cv2.imwrite("../matchedImages/"+'image_' + str(index) + "_" + str(counter) + '.png'  ,histImage)
            #rotatedImage = cv2.line(rotatedImage, (), (), (0, 255, 0), 9) 
            cv2.imwrite("../matchedImages/"+'ref_' + str(index) + "_" + str(counter) + '.png'  ,crop_img)
```

First, I load the original satellite image and pad it so I don't lose information due to the rotation, second, I load one of the matched historical images as well as the matched keypoints of the two images (i.e. a list of x_hist, y_hist, x_present_day, y_present_day). Third, I compute the rotation angle between the two images (which works) and fourth, I crop the image (and fifth, I save the images).

**Problem**: As stated the rotation works fine, but my program ends up cropping the wrong part of the image.

I think that, due to the rotation, the boundaries (i.e. left, right, top, bottom) are no longer correct and I think this is where my problem lies, but I am not sure how to fix this problem.

**Information that might help:**

- The images are both scaled the same way (so one pixel = approx. 1m)
- I have at least 6 keypoints for each image

Comment: Perhaps post the images so we can see what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the error in my computation. The bounding boxes of the cutout area were wrongly converted into the present-day image.
So this:

```
x = int(points[0][2] - points[0][0])
y = int(points[1][2] - points[1][0])
```

was swapped with this:

```
v = [pointBefore[0],pointBefore[1],1]
# Perform the actual rotation and return the image
calculated = np.dot(m,v)
newPoint = (int(calculated[0]- points[0][0]),int(calculated[1]- points[0][1]))
```

where m(=M) is from the transformation:

```
def rotate_bound(image, angle):
    # grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the
    # center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH)), M
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your code yet but would it be due to you mixing up the x's and y's ? Check the OpenCV documentation to make sure the variables you import are in the correct order.
During my limited time and experience with opencv, it is quite weird because sometimes, it asks for for example, BGR instead of RGB values. (In my programme, not yours)

Also, you seem to have a bunch of lists, make sure the list[x][y] is not mixed up as list[y][x]